# How to bring my element back after using display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On click I can hide my div element with `display:none` but can't get it back with `display:inline` when button is clicked

```
document.getElementById("red").onclick = function (){
    document.getElementById("red").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("back").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementsById("red").style.display = "inline";
}
```

Comment: getElementsById ...? is that a typo ...?

Comment: `getElementById` instead of `getElementsById`...

Comment: you can use `visibility:hidden` instead.

Comment: Step one, check the console: `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function`

Comment: used getElementById instead of getElementsbyId still not working

Comment: well, as you have not shared any HTML , minimal example here:: https://jsfiddle.net/31wajbg7/1/ works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Hi your script has typo error.
getElementsById is having Elements instead of Element.
Alway use Console for error messages it will help you alot :).
Cheers !!!
Your script should look like this .

```
 document.getElementById("red").onclick = function (){
    document.getElementById("red").style.display = "none";
       }
document.getElementById("back").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("red").style.display = "inline";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example:** `display:none` to `display:inline` toggle.

```js
document.getElementById("red").onclick = function (){
    document.getElementById("red").style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById("back").onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("red").style.display = "inline";
}
```

```css
#red 
{
color:#fff;
background:red;
padding:8px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="red">RED (Click me)</div>

<button id="back">Back</button>
```

You can always see the errors in the console and figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use a class for styling and also use Element.addEventListener() for the events.

```
var red = document.getElementById('red')
var back = document.getElementById('back')
red.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.add('hidden')
})
back.addEventListener('click', function() {
    red.classList.remove('hidden')
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cnzabf1a/

Documentation on:

- [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Answer (score 0):

If your're using flex using 'inline-flex' may be better:

```
document.getElementById("red").style.display = "inline-flex";
```